# Angular-CLI with SASS offline

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am trying to compile an Angular project with SASS using Angular-CLI.  My server is behind a firewall, and cannot pull files from the Internet.   It can, however, connect to an npm repo that has pre-approved packages. I have downloaded and copied **win32-x64-48_binding.node** to a local folder and set the **SASS-BINARY-PATH** environment variable to point to this file.

I have created the project using the command:

```
ng new myproject --style=sass
```

Then I restored the packages with:

```
npm install --sass-binary-path=d:\path\to\win32-x64-48_binding.node
```

So far, so good.  Finally when I run:

```
ng build
```

I get the error:

> *Error in ./src/app/app.component.sass
>   Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'd:\Projects\Angular\myproject\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'*
>
> ...

I don't have a vendor directory because I installed the binding.node using a different binary path.  What do I need to do to get the ng build to work with this offline/SASS scenario?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No.  I hacked around the issue by copying the binding.node file into the location it's looking for inside of my build script.

Answer (score 0):

Add the *SASS_BINARY_PATH* variable to your System Environment Variables. This is because [binding parameters](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#binary-configuration-parameters) for node-sass only work during *npm install*.  They won't be used during compilation; such as, `ng build` or `ng serve`